# How to use RPG program to access DB2 db on IBM system i

Tags: db2, rpg, ibm-midrange

I am a newer for RPG program. Now I want use RPG program to access DB2 db on IBM i system. For example insert one record to DB, update one record, delete one record. Could you give some sample code? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Look up information about  READ, CHAIN, UPDATE, WRITE, DELETE in the [ILE RPG Programmer's Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/books/sc092507.pdf) [PDF] That is where you should start reading. There is usually example code in the books. If you have more specific question, just keep tagging them `RPG`. I watch for those often.

Comment: why do you always remove the as/400 & iseries tag and replace them with ibm-i?  It makes it quite a bit harder to keep up on the questions and for the purpose of this site it would seem much better to put all three on.

Comment: Because it is now the IBM i. Maybe I'll just add ibm-i then. Also to keep SO cleaner. We have `as400`, `iseries`, and `ibm-i`. I am sure there are a couple others I am missing. Standardization is a good thing. I just choose the current name as the standard. Take this to meta if you want to chat more.

Comment: @Brandon Peterson - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70086/as400-iseries-and-ibm-i-are-all-the-same-system